# Why does not "localhost" work as MySQL host, but "MyPCName" does?

Tags: php, mysql, localhost

I'm trying to connect to MySQL from PHP (WordPress) on Windows / IIS 7.5 and this is what happens:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'DevPC');        // -> works
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');    // -> connection error
```

Strange is that on another machine (Windows Server + IIS 7.5), `localhost` works just fine. What can be causing this? Some PHP settings? MySQL settings?

Comment: Remember that `localhost` uses domain sockets (by default), not TCP/IP. Use `127.0.0.1` to force TCP/IP. This may alter the observed behavior and trying the explicit loopback address can help narrow the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should give us the error output from the connection. Are you sure it's not a user access problem? Remember that `user@DevPC` is not the same as `user@localhost` when connecting to mysql. Even if both hostnames translates to the same IP.

Comment: Great, that was it. I had a user with the "%" as the host matching rule which I thought would allow this user from any host but apparently not from `localhost`.

Answer (score 3):

> On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name `localhost` specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a `--port` or `-P` option is given to specify a port number.

Instead of `localhost` use `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Sorry I should have specified that this is on Windows. Does the same reply apply?

Comment: BTW I have tried to change 'MyPCName' to '127.0.0.1' and it results in connection error.

Comment: @Borek: The quote is from the MySQL manual and it speaks about UNIX which is not Windows, so I'd say no. If you have connection problems on windows check your firewall settings. I suggest you try with the commandline client first because you get the feedback more easily. Change the connection parameters and troubleshoot them until it works: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can check

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

to know if the line

```
127.0.0.1
```

localhost is there.

```
/etc/resolv.conf in linux
```

Comment: On both machines, 127.0.0.1 rule is commented out and there is a message that "localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself". That's why I find it strange that `localhost` works on one machine and doesn't on another.

Comment: maybe your dns system is doing it wrong.. do a ping to localhost and see what is your result. it should return 127.0.0.1